# c++ address string -> long

Tags: c++, string, long-integer, memory-address

I got an adress example: 0x003533 , its a string but to use it i need it to be a LONG but i dont know how to do it :S has anybody a solution?

so string: "0x003533" to long 0x003533 ??

Answer (score 5):

Use [strtol()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strtol.html) as in:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

// ...
{
   // ...
   // Assume str is an std::string containing the value
   long value = strtol(str.c_str(),0,0);
   // ...
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s("0x003533");
  long x;
  istringstream(s) >> hex >> x;
  cout << hex << x << endl; // prints 3533
  cout << dec << x << endl; // prints 13619
}
```

**EDIT:**

As Potatocorn said in the comments, you can also use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#motivation) as shown below:

```
long x = 0L;
try {
  x = lexical_cast<long>("0x003533");
}
catch(bad_lexical_cast const & blc) {
  // handle the exception
}
```